# Passing kwargs to django admin form

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have a couple of models, for example:

```
class Product (models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(
        max_length = 255,
    )
    supplier = models.ForeignKey(
        Supplier,
        blank=True,
        null=True
    )
    min_level = models.IntegerField(
        default = 10,
    )
    quantity = models.IntegerField(
        default = 0
    )

class ReOrder (models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(
        Product,
    )
    order_quantity = models.IntegerField(
        default = 0
    )
    order_date = models.DateField(
        default = datetime.datetime.now()
    )
    received = models.BooleanField(
        default = False
    )
    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % (self.product)
```

When I'm listing my Products within Django Admin I have a ReOrder button. 
 When click I want to go straight to the Django Admin ReOrder Add ReOrder.product defaulting to the Product prefilled

Getting the button etc in place is fine but I cannot work out how to pass the Product.id through.

I'm trying: `reverse('admin:inventory_reorder_add', kwargs={'product_id' : obj.pk })` where obj.pk is the Product.  This is giving me

> Reverse for 'inventory_reorder_add' with keyword arguments
>   '{'product_id': 31L}' not found

How do I make a call and have the field pre-selected within admin?

Thanks for your help.

Below is the complete ProductAdmin class.

```
class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['title', 'get_sku', 'get_ebaylink', 'quantity', 'quantity_status','account_actions','weekly_stock','monthly_stock','quarterly_stock']
    ordering = ['title', 'quantity', ]
    inlines = [SkuInline, EbayLinkInline]
    search_fields = ('title', 'sku__sku', 'ebaylink__custom_label', )
    fields = ['title', 'supplier', 'min_level', 'quantity']

    def get_sku(self, obj):
        try :
            instance = Sku.objects.filter(product=obj)
            msg = ''
            for i in instance:
                msg += i.sku + ', '
            return msg
        except : return None
    get_sku.short_description = 'Amazon Sku'
    get_sku.admin_order_field = 'sku__sku'

    def get_ebaylink(self, obj):
        try:
            instance = EbayLink.objects.filter(product=obj)
            msg = ''
            for i in instance:
                msg += i.custom_label + ', '
            return msg
        except: return None
    get_ebaylink.short_description = 'Ebay Custom Label'
    get_ebaylink.admin_order_field = 'ebaylink__custom_label'

    def quantity_status(self, obj):
        if obj.min_level > obj.quantity:
            return '<div style="width:100%%; height:100%%; background-color:red;">%s</div>' % (obj.quantity-obj.min_level)
        return '%s' % (obj.quantity-obj.min_level)
    quantity_status.short_description = 'Variance from min level'
    quantity_status.allow_tags = True
    quantity_status.admin_order_field = 'total'

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(ProductAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
        qs = qs.annotate(total=ExpressionWrapper(F('quantity')-F('min_level'), output_field=DecimalField())).order_by('total')
        return qs

    def get_urls(self):
        urls = super(ProductAdmin, self).get_urls()
        custom_urls = [
            url(r'^(?P<product_id>.+)/add-stock/$', self.admin_site.admin_view(self.add_stock), name='add-stock',),
            url(r'^(?P<product_id>.+)/delete-stock/$', self.admin_site.admin_view(self.delete_stock), name='delete-stock',),
            url(r'^(?P<product_id>.+)/reorder-stock/$', self.admin_site.admin_view(self.delete_stock), name='reorder-stock',),
        ]
        return custom_urls + urls

    def account_actions(self, obj):
        return format_html(
            '<a class="button" href="{}">+</a>&nbsp;'
            '<a class="button" href="{}">-</a>&nbsp;'
            '<a class="button" href="{}">Reorder</a>',
            reverse('admin:add-stock', args=[obj.pk]),
            reverse('admin:delete-stock', args=[obj.pk]),
            reverse('admin:inventory_reorder_add', kwargs={'product_id' : obj.pk }),
        )
    account_actions.short_description = 'Account Actions'
    account_actions.allow_tags = True

    def add_stock(self, request, product_id, *args, **kwargs):
        product = Product.objects.get(pk=product_id)
        product.quantity += 1
        product.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))

    def delete_stock(self, request, product_id, *args, **kwargs):
        product = Product.objects.get(pk=product_id)
        product.quantity -= 1
        product.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))

admin.site.register(Product, ProductAdmin)
```

Comment: You don't seem to have defined any URL called "inventory_reorder_add" in your get_urls method.

Comment: @danielroseman That's because my app is `inventory`, the model is `reorder` and I want to `add` so I thought admin created it automatically?  If I don't set any `kwargs` this is where it takes me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass default values to an admin edit page via the querystring rather than the URL.

```
'<a class="button" href="{}?product_id={}">Reorder</a>',
...
reverse('admin:inventory_reorder_add'), obj.pk
```